# JS script not running if wrapped in IIFE (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is potentially an Angular issue, but I suspect it is more related to general JS. I am setting up an Angular app, and have it all running good so far.

I have broken it up into different modules `app`,`app.core`,`app.components` etc.

I have come across an odd issue now, where I have tried to create a directive to use across all modules and am a little stumped on this one. I can get this to work as it should, with the template displaying in my view:

```
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app.components')
    .directive('navBar', function() {
        return {
            controller: 'Main',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            link: function(){
              console.log('Directive link')
            },
            template: 'Directive template'
        };
    });
```

However, when I wrap it in an IIFE :

```
    (function() {
        'use strict';
        angular.module('app.components')
        .directive('navBar', function() {
            return {
                link: function(){
                  console.log('Directive link')
                },
                template: 'Directive template'
            };
        });
     });
```

It fails, bizarrely. All of my other modules have been written the same way as the second example and work fine.

Any guidance much appreciated.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: This piece of code is never actually invoked. What do you expect to happen? Did you mean IIFE (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)?

Comment: Just invoke the function: (function(){...})();

Comment: Post updated to IIFE. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closures need to be invoked for their code to run:

`(function () {...}());`

or

`(function () {...})();`

Comment: Ah! Thanks very much. I had just copy/pasted the first line while not correctly writing the last line.